# How to find duplicate dates in a list and group the description

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object like this:

```
public DateLookupItem()
{
    Id = int.MinValue;
    Date = DateTime.MinValue;
    Description = string.Empty;
}
```

I have a list of the above object. And now I need to find a way to group by the same Date and concatenate the description of that group.

I need to output something like this as a string if 2 dates are the same in the list and another is different:

```
(Description/Description) Date, (Description) Date
```

I have the following code that works but is hard to read/follow. `dateList` is a `DateLookupItem` List:

```
string comma = string.Empty;

List<IGrouping<DateTime, DateLookupItem>> sameDates = dateList.GroupBy(x => x.Date).ToList();

foreach(IGrouping<DateTime, DateLookupItem> date in sameDates )
{
    string forwardSlash = string.Empty;
    displayDate += comma + "(";

    foreach(DateLookupItem d in date)
    {
        displayDate += forwardSlash + d.Description;
        forwardSlash = "/";
    }

    displayDate += ")" + " " + CELPDateTime.GetStringFromDateTime(date.Key);
    comma = ", ";
}
```

Is there a way to convert this to linq? Or refactor it so that it is easier to read/understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var sameDates = from d in dateList
        group d.Description by d.Date.Date;

var displayDate = 
    String.Join(",", 
                sameDates
                .Select(date=>string.Format("({0}) {1}", 
                                   String.Join("/", date), 
                                    date.Key)
                       )
                );
```

You'll need to replace the `date.Key` with `CELPDateTime.GetStringFromDateTime(date.Key)`

Here's the rest of the code I used:

```
void Main()
{
    var dateList = new List<DateLookupItem>();
    for(int i=0; i< 100; ++i) dateList.Add(new UserQuery.DateLookupItem());

    var sameDates = from d in dateList
            group d.Description by d.Date.Date;

    var displayDate = 
        String.Join(",", 
                    sameDates
                    .Select(date=>string.Format("({0}) {1}", String.Join("/", date), date.Key)));


    displayDate.Dump();
}


public class DateLookupItem
{
    static readonly Random rnd = new Random();
        public DateLookupItem()
        {
            Id = rnd.Next();
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(rnd.Next(-5, 5) );
            Description = new string((char) rnd.Next(65, 91), rnd.Next(10)+1);
        }
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = new List<DateLookupItem>();

var result = from d in data
    group d by d.Date
    into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key,
        descs = g.Select(gg => gg.Description)
    };

var output = string.Join(",", result
    .Select(r => string.Format("({0}) {1}", string.Join("/", r.descs), 
        CELPDateTime.GetStringFromDateTime(r.Key))));
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't see your till after I posted mine, but - damn-- they're close.  Note that you don't have to group by the entire object.  Choosing just the field we need let's you avoid the `into` & `select`.

Comment: That's a good tip, saw the clever group by condition, nice. Thanks.

Comment: I like this one. One improvement might be to format your description in the initial `select`, i.e: `descs = string.Join("/", g.Select(gg => gg.Description))`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner way to do it:

```
var dliList = new List<DateLookupItem>();

// Create a list of ten items. Every third one has the same date.
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{
    dliList.Add(new DateLookupItem
        {
            Id = i,
            Date = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("1-{0}-2014", 
                (i % 3 == 0) ? "3" : i.ToString())),
            Description = i.ToString(),
        });
}

Console.WriteLine(
    string.Join(", ",
                dliList.GroupBy(x => x.Date)
                        .Select(
                            dliGrp =>
                                string.Format("({0}), {1}", 
                                    string.Join("/", dliGrp.Select(d => d.Description)),
                                    dliGrp.Key))));
```